# Network setup for office

Tags: networking

I have been given the task of setting up a network for an office as an exercise in my networking module. The problem is as follows:

- 10 Offices with 2 devices each.
- Server room that has a server with 4 ports and a printer.
- Reception with 4 devices.
- Lab 1 with 50 PCs and a printer.
- Lab 2 with 130 PCs.
- Lab 3 with 260 PCs.

We were also asked to use as little address space as possible with the given devices.

So here is what I did. I set up 5 networks, the first one consisting of all the offices and the reception. The second one being just the server room. The third, fourth and fifth being lab 1, lab 2 and lab 3 respectively. So;

- N1: 24 Devices.
- N2: 6 Devices.
- N3: 50 Devices.
- N4: 130 Devices.
- N5: 260 Devices.

The subnets and network IDs:

- N1: Sub = 255.255.255.224 and ID = 192.168.1.224/27
- N2: Sub = 255.255.255.230 and ID = 192.168.1.230/28
- N3: Sub = 255.255.255.192 and ID = 192.168.1.192/26
- N4: Sub = 255.255.255.0 and ID = 192.168.1.0/24
- N5: Sub = 255.255.254.0 and ID = 192.168.254.0/23

I then suggested putting in a switch for each network which in turn connects to the central router. Between the switch and devices I would use fast ethernet, and between the switches and router gigabit.

I am extremely new to this and would really appreciate some insight into my solution, I am open to criticisms, be it positive or negative. I also want to ask:

- Is it safe to use similar network IDs? Or is it just a preference thing?
- Would you guys suggest that I rather combine some networks together, for example number 3, 4 and 5. Or maybe some other combinations?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: This sounds like an IT problem. Stackoverflow is about programming. Maybe the site "Serverfault" (https://serverfault.com) from Stack-Exchange is more suitable..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**At first count your devices in 2^x steps**:

Add 2 reserved IPs (one for the gateway and one for the broadcast)

- N1: (Office) 2^4 = 32 Devices
- N2: (Serverroom) 2^3 = 8 Devices
- N3: (Reception) 2^3 = 8 Devices
- N4: (Lab 1) 2^6 = 64 Devices
- N5: (Lab 2) 2^8 = 256 Devices
- N6: (Lab 3) 2^9 = 512 Devices

**Then setup the IP address of each subnetwork:**

The best way is write them down in binary:

Your private address range is: 1100 0000.1010 1000.0000 0000.0000 0000 /16

- N6: 1100 0000.1010 1000.0000 000X.XXXX XXXX /23
- N5: 1100 0000.1010 1000.0000 0010.XXXX XXXX /24
- N4: 1100 0000.1010 1000.0000 0010.00XX XXXX /26
- N1: 1100 0000.1010 1000.0000 0010.0100 XXXX /28
- N2: 1100 0000.1010 1000.0000 0010.0101 0XXX /29
- N3: 1100 0000.1010 1000.0000 0010.0101 1XXX /29

X is marking the possible IPs in your subnetwork

**Using similar network IDs**

If I understand your question correctly: No, it is not. The words similar and safe are not really combineable.

**combining some networks**:

I think your exercise is to separate the networks for security reasons. So you shouldn't combine the networks N3, N4 and N5.